# Let $(\mathbb R^3 , *)$ be a group with operation $(x,y,t)*(x',y',t'):=( x+x',y+y',t+t'+\dfrac 12(xy'-x 'y ) ) $, what is the center of this group?

Tags: group-theory

Let $*$ be defined on $\mathbb R^3$ such that $(x,y,t)*(x',y',t'):=( x+x',y+y',t+t'+\dfrac 12(xy'-x 'y ) )$ , I can show that $(\mathbb R^3 , *)$ is a group ; I want to find the center of this group , Please help .

Comment: This is in fact a Heisenberg group, for those interested.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Suppose $(x',y',t')$ is in the center.  Then $(x,y,t)*(x',y',t')=(x',y',t')*(x,y,t)$ for all $(x,y,t)\in\mathbb{R}^3$.  This translates to $$(x+x',y+y',t+t'+\frac{1}{2}(xy'-x'y))=(x'+x,y'+y, t'+t+\frac{1}{2}(x'y-xy'))$$
Since addition is commutative, the condition simplifies to $xy'-x'y=x'y-xy'$ for all $x,y$.  This rearranges to $2xy'=2x'y$.  The only way this holds for all $x,y$ is if $x'=y'=0$.